# MS Access Restart Number Sequence

Tags: ms-access

trying to do a sequence count in MS Access where the count sequence resets based on another field, so example below, trying to figure out `ColB`:

```
ColA ColB
4566 1
5677 1
5677 2
5677 3
8766 1
8766 2
1223 1
```

Think it might have something to do with the `DCount()` function, unsure.  Would very much appreciate the help ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating a group sequence number in Access query is fairly common topic. Requires a unique identifier field, autonumber should serve.

Using DCount():

`SELECT *, DCount("*", "table", "ColA=" & [ColA] & " AND ID<" & ID) + 1 AS GrpSeq FROM table;`

Or with correlated subquery:

`SELECT *, (SELECT Count(*) FROM table AS D WHERE D.ColA=table.ColA AND D.ID<table.ID)+1 AS GrpSeq FROM table;`

An alternative to calculating in query is to use RunningSum property of textbox on a Report with Sorting & Grouping settings.