# Lookup value in Access table without a unique identifier using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table like this:

```
+-----------+------+
| TableName | Flag |  
+-----------+------+
| TableG    |    0 |  
| TableE    |    0 |  
| TableR    |    1 |  
| TableL    |    1 |  
| TableN    |    0 |
```

What I'm trying to do is have a function that looks up every TableName where Flag=1 so that I can assign each table where Flag=1 to a button in a form (e.g. assign the first instance to Button1, etc.).  The tricky part is that this table cannot be edited, so no unique ID/count can be assigned to easily grab items.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- DLookup does not handle having multiple lookup matches (e.g. DLookup("TableName", "MyTable", "Flag=1") would not allow me to access all the values where Flag=1), so I don't think I can use that to store them in an array
- I've tried using a RecordSet (see below), but I could not figure out how to have the SQL string automatically add a count so that each table name could be referenced (e.g. TableNameRS(1) to pull the name of the first table with Flag=1)

```
    Public Function TableNameRS(TableID As Integer)
     Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
     Dim SQL As String
     Dim Name As Variant
     SQL = "select TableName, COUNT(TableName) from MyTable where Flag=1"
     Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
     Name = RS("TableName")
     TableNameRS = Name
     RS.Close
    End Function
```

I am out of ideas - what are my options here?

Comment: Why use buttons and not a combobox or listbox?

Comment: Won't the number of records change and therefore the number of buttons required also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of records and buttons are fixed, say 10, and buttons have names like btn1, btn2, etc., consider a procedure like:

```
Public Sub TableNameRS(TableID As Integer)
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TableName FROM MyTable WHERE Flag=1 ORDER BY TableName")
    For x = 1 to 10
        Me("btn" & x).Caption = RS("TableName")
        RS.MoveNext
    Next
    RS.Close
End Function
```

Procedure can be called in form Open event. Then code in button Click event can pass its caption as an argument to whatever other procedure needs to take action with TableName value.

Calculating a sequence identifier in Access query is a common topic [MS Access Restart Number Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565228/ms-access-restart-number-sequence).

Assuming TableName values are unique:

```
SELECT TableName, DCount("*", "table", "TableName<'" & [TableName] & "' AND Flag=1")+1 AS Seq, 
FROM table
WHERE Flag=1
ORDER BY TableName;
```

Can use that query as RecordSource for form or report or execute DLookup() on it.

Be aware any change in filter will impact sequence calculation.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer!