# Serial with conditions starting from variable number ms-access

Tags: ms-access, serialization

Guys i have this function which some of you helped me with. I tried to add one condition and i couldn’t

My Function:

```
Sub MakeNum2()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, intS As Integer, strG As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Warehouse] & [TransType] AS Grp, TblImportTemp.zdate, TblImportTemp.Doc From TblImportTemp ORDER BY [Warehouse] & [TransType], TblImportTemp.zdate;")

strG = rs!grp
While Not rs.EOF
    If strG = rs!grp Then
        intS = intS + 1
        rs.Edit
        rs!Doc = intS
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Else
        intS = 0
        strG = rs!grp
    End If
Wend

End Sub
```

I don’t need it to start the serializing from Number 1 So The Condition i need to add is to get the last Doc Number From QryLastDoc where Grp (In My Function) = Grp2 In QryLastDoc And Set this number as the beginning of Serial then proceed to add 1 for each new doc as usual.
QryLastDoc

```
SELECT QryTransTopDoc.Warehouse, QryTransTopDoc.Type, Last(QryTransTopDoc.Doc) AS LastOfDoc, [Warehouse] & [Type] AS Grp2
FROM QryTransTopDoc
GROUP BY QryTransTopDoc.Warehouse, QryTransTopDoc.Type, [Warehouse] & [Type];
```

The Result: the first record will be the last doc number from QryLastDoc +1 then the following will be doc+1 Thanks in Advance

EDIT #1 : It couldn’t be done by Dlookup Guys

```
`intS = Nz(DLookup("Doc", "QryTransTopDoc", "Grp2='" & rs!Grp & "'"), 0)`
```

Dlookup Result will be the ground number for serializing meaning the first record DOC will be Dlookup+1 then the following records will be DOC+1 I wish i could explain more . Thanks again

Comment: What does "couldn't make it work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Should provide code that has issue.

Comment: No i Don’t Know how , Its not that simple for me because its not always get the last doc and add 1 to it , It just do that in the first record to get the first serial to Go on with the function as usual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use DLookup() domain aggregate function to pull last value generated to set variable with initial value outside loop. Then increment the variable within loop.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, intS As Integer, strG As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Warehouse] & [TransType] AS Grp, TblImportTemp.zdate, TblImportTemp.Doc From TblImportTemp ORDER BY [Warehouse] & [TransType], TblImportTemp.zdate;")
intS = Nz(DLookup("Doc", "QryTransTopDoc", "Grp2='" & rs!Grp & "'"), 0)
strG = rs!grp
While Not rs.EOF
    If strG = rs!grp Then
        intS = intS + 1
        rs.Edit
        rs!Doc = intS
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Else
        intS = Nz(DLookup("Doc", "QryTransTopDoc", "Grp2='" & rs!Grp & "'"), 0)
        strG = rs!grp
    End If
Wend
```

Or use DMax() on table.

Alternatively, don't save this value to table and instead calculate when needed. [MS Access Restart Number Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565228/ms-access-restart-number-sequence)

Comment: It won’t Work , The thing is its not always like that , this step will be for the first record only , If i use dlookup the doc number will be the same for all records because it gets the last doc number from the query which will not be changed in this procedure , i wish i could explain more

Comment: Yes, use DLookup or DMax to pull value and set variable with starting value then increment the variable for subsequent values - assuming you are using a loop as shown in your question.

Comment: Could you apply it to the function please ?